# How to fill out a table using the primary key of two others (automatically)?

Tags: mysql

so, I have 3 tables:

- teachers
- -------
- id_teacher PK
- name_teacher

- grades
- -------
- id_grade PK
- name_grade

- activities
- -------
- id_activity PK AI
- id_teacher FK
- id_grade FK
- name_activity NULL

I want my database in mySQL to combine all the teachers with all the grades in the table "activities" and leaving the "name_activity" field as NULL to fill it out later. I want to do it automatically. Does it make sense ? How can I do it?

or should I take another approach?

Comment: I assume `activities.id_activity` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Right?

Comment: that's correect, sorry I didn't specify it

Answer (score 1):

You want a Cartesian product which can be achieved via a [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join)

```
INSERT INTO `activities` (id_teacher, id_grade)
SELECT t.id_teacher, g.id_grade
FROM `teachers` t, `grades` g
```